# Is setState a queue data structure?

Tags: reactjs

Given:

```
   this.setState({"data1": ''});
   this.setState({"data2": ''});
   this.setState({"data3": ''}, this.runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete);
```

Is `setState` a queue data structure (FIFO)?  In other words, is the above code safe in that `runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete` will run last in all circumstances?  Or do I need to write the code as a series of callbacks:

```
  this.setState({"data1": ''}, this.setNext);
  setNext(){
     this.setState({"data2": ''}, this.setNextNext);
  }
  setNextNext() {
     this.setState({"data3": ''}, this.runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete);
  }
```

Or alternatively and assuming idempotence:

```
this.setState({"accrualName": ''}, this.runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete);
this.setState({"accrueRate": ''}, this.runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete);
this.setState({"hoursPer": ''}, this.runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete);
```

Comment: Might be worth looking into the `componentDidUpdate` hook. This is invoked immediately after the updates are passed to DOM. This might be a better home for `runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete()`

Answer (score 0):

The first code is definitely not safe: `setState` is an async operation.
After the first `setState` is invoked, react will at some point re-render. So no way of telling if and when the second `setState` will fire.

The same problem with the third code snippet, because it also has multiple `setState` in a row.

The second version will probably work, but I would advise against doing another `setState` inside the callback in this way.

As suggested in comment, a more react-way to chain states is probably something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.data3) {
    this.runMeAfterAllStateUpdatesComplete();
  } else if (this.state.data2) {
    this.setState({ data3 : '' });
  } else if (this.state.data1) {
    this.setState({ data2 : '' });}
  }
}
```